# Driver for FresLogic fl2000

Tags: drivers, usb-drive, gpu-driver, vga

Please help, I want to use FresLogic FL2000 USB TO VGA.
But I can't find the right driver.
Have tried following the steps at https://github.com/FrescoLogic/FL2000
but still can't.

Comment: Too vague, sorry. Most of us will not have a FreshLogic so can't help. Please provide an error or notice you got when doing the installation or from a log in /var/log/ that shows something regarding this device. What did the test run, as explained in the link, provide as information?

Answer (score 0):

The module included in GitHub is only kernel module. It creates /dev/fl2000-0 (or -1) and allows you to talk to the device. It does not handle extending your display to that device.